# Spliting a comma delimitted string into several columns and asigning 0 to nospace

Tags: string, r, replace, split, strsplit

In my `data.frame` a vector `x` containing text strings (with six values (from 0 to 100) separated by comma inside each string) in this format:

```
x[1] "3,2,4,34,2,9"
x[2] "45,,67,,,"
x[3] ",,,,99,"
```

Here is the link to the actual vector I am having problems with: `x.cvs` [x.cvs](https://db.tt/9wBDAWjf)

Unfortunately, the value of "0" is recorded as "an empty no space" between the two commas, or before the first comma, or after the last comma.

It would be great first to be able to transform it into:

```
x[1]  "3,2,4,34,2,9"
x[2]  "45,0,67,0,0,0"
x[3]  "0,0,0,0,99,0"
```

But most importantly, I would like to split this vector into 6 different vectors x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6 and each of them to take the value from the string, and replace "no space" between commas with "0", for example, the result should be:

```
x1[3] 0
x6[2] 0
```

I think the strsplit() would have worked if there has been a value between commas, but since there is no value, not even an empty space, I am not sure what is the right way to proceed, without getting NAs.

I tried the following, but it does give me a lot of errors:

```
x<- as.character(x)
x <- gsub(",,", ",0,", x)
x <- gsub(", ,", ",0,", x)
splitx = do.call("rbind", (strsplit(x, ",")))
splitx = data.frame(apply(splitx, 2, as.numeric))
names(splitx) = paste("x", 1:6, sep = "")
```

I get errors...

```
In rbind(c("51", "59", "59", "60", "51", "51"), c("51", "59", "59",  :
  number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 10994)
 In apply(splitx, 2, as.numeric) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: Your question is not clear on the actual input format of your data nor your desired output format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two alternatives to consider, depending on what you are actually expecting as your output.

The first option outputs a set of vectors, but I find that to be a little bit unnecessary and can quickly litter your workspace with lots of objects.

The second option, which I prefer, creates a convenient `data.frame` with each row representing one of the items from your vector "x".

#### Sample Data

```
x <- vector()
x[1] <- "3,2,4,34,2,9"
x[2] <- "45,,67,,,"
x[3] <- ",,,,99,"
```

#### Option 1

```
Names <- paste0("A", seq_along(x))
for (i in seq_along(x)) {
  assign(Names[i], {Z <- scan(text=x[i], sep=","); Z[is.na(Z)] <- 0; Z})
}
A1
# [1]  3  2  4 34  2  9
A2
# [1] 45  0 67  0  0  0
A3
# [1]  0  0  0  0 99  0
```

#### Option 2

```
Z <- read.csv(text = x, header = FALSE)
Z[is.na(Z)] <- 0
Z
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
# 1  3  2  4 34  2  9
# 2 45  0 67  0  0  0
# 3  0  0  0  0 99  0
```

Extracting values from a `data.frame` is as easy as specifying the desired rows and columns.

```
Z[1, 3]
# [1] 4
Z[2, 4]
# [1] 0
Z[3, c(1, 3, 5)]
#   V1 V3 V5
# 3  0  0 99
```

Comment: **Option 2** would work well for me, but the problem is that whenever there is an empty space in the text string at the first element (before the comma), it does not appear as `0`, but as `NULL` or an `(empty field)`. Why is that, do you think?

Here is an example: 
     `Z[3, c(1, 3, 5)]`
      `#   V1 V3 V5`
      `# 3  NULL 0 99`

Comment: @inarts, Without some example code that replicates what you're describing, it's really tough to say. If you think it is something to do with whitespace, add a `strip.white = TRUE` to the `read.csv` line and see if that helps.

Comment: @ Ananda Mahto, the reason i get the `NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0` is because, I have some strings (in some rows) that are recorded as `NULL` (when converted they appear as `NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0`). However, when there is `no space` before the first comma (and no number), when converted it appears as an empty input. I followed your suggestion with `strip.white = TRUE`, but it does not solve neither the first, nor the second issue. Should I try to eliminate rows containing `NULL` first? 
Here is a vector I am having problems with `x.cvs` [x.cvs](https://db.tt/9wBDAWjf) in case you can look at it.

Comment: @inarts, you can try something like `X <- scan("path/to/x.csv", what=""); Z <- read.csv(text = X[X != "NULL"], header = FALSE)` to get rid of the "NULL" lines.

Comment: combining the tips you provided in your replies have worked for my data perfectly. The results appear as expected. I no longer see NULL, nor empty spaces.